# how to plot heatmap for a single gene across tissues to see whether it has SNPs for the tissue or not

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, plot, heatmap

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
dput(chr22_gene[,1:49])
structure(c(0.0531016390078734, -0.00413407782001034, -0.035434632568444, 
0.00968736935965742, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.1983546, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.54054634049041e-06, -1.02538094713665e-06, 
1.75405521957808e-07, 2.81925504836742e-08, -0.00286734456709225, 
0.00467948313596414, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0104604233349395, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0259856283860652, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0107519090954185, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0147898755312336, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0314582291188165, 0, 0, 0.00500515393772989, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(11L, 49L), dimnames = list(
    c("rs1041770_ENSG00000283633.1", "rs12628452_ENSG00000283633.1", 
    "rs915675_ENSG00000283633.1", "rs11089130_ENSG00000283633.1", 
    "rs738820_ENSG00000240972.1", "rs7290144_ENSG00000240972.1", 
    "rs2298386_ENSG00000240972.1", "rs3788374_ENSG00000240972.1", 
    "rs9830_ENSG00000240972.1", "rs5760687_ENSG00000240972.1", 
    "rs6003388_ENSG00000240972.1"), c("en_Adipose_Subcutaneous.db", 
    "en_Adipose_Visceral_Omentum.db", "en_Adrenal_Gland.db", 
    "en_Artery_Aorta.db", "en_Artery_Coronary.db", "en_Artery_Tibial.db", 
    "en_Brain_Amygdala.db", "en_Brain_Anterior_cingulate_cortex_BA24.db", 
    "en_Brain_Caudate_basal_ganglia.db", "en_Brain_Cerebellar_Hemisphere.db", 
    "en_Brain_Cerebellum.db", "en_Brain_Cortex.db", "en_Brain_Frontal_Cortex_BA9.db", 
    "en_Brain_Hippocampus.db", "en_Brain_Hypothalamus.db", "en_Brain_Nucleus_accumbens_basal_ganglia.db", 
    "en_Brain_Putamen_basal_ganglia.db", "en_Brain_Spinal_cord_cervical_c.1.db", 
    "en_Brain_Substantia_nigra.db", "en_Breast_Mammary_Tissue.db", 
    "en_Cells_Cultured_fibroblasts.db", "en_Cells_EBV.transformed_lymphocytes.db", 
    "en_Colon_Sigmoid.db", "en_Colon_Transverse.db", "en_Esophagus_Gastroesophageal_Junction.db", 
    "en_Esophagus_Mucosa.db", "en_Esophagus_Muscularis.db", "en_Heart_Atrial_Appendage.db", 
    "en_Heart_Left_Ventricle.db", "en_Kidney_Cortex.db", "en_Liver.db", 
    "en_Lung.db", "en_Minor_Salivary_Gland.db", "en_Muscle_Skeletal.db", 
    "en_Nerve_Tibial.db", "en_Ovary.db", "en_Pancreas.db", "en_Pituitary.db", 
    "en_Prostate.db", "en_Skin_Not_Sun_Exposed_Suprapubic.db", 
    "en_Skin_Sun_Exposed_Lower_leg.db", "en_Small_Intestine_Terminal_Ileum.db", 
    "en_Spleen.db", "en_Stomach.db", "en_Testis.db", "en_Thyroid.db", 
    "en_Uterus.db", "en_Vagina.db", "en_Whole_Blood.db")))
```

I want to plot a heatmap to see how many rsids or snps are present for one gene across tissues and their magnitude and their direction
So basically let say for one gene:
it has many rsids, I want to have one color correspond to snps, and one color to correspond to different magnitude let say for this gene it has the same rsid across 2 tissues, then their value is different so these two tissues should have different color scale and if the rsid between two tissue for the gene is in different direction one is +ve and one is -ve then different color like tissue 1 which has rsid in +ve it should be green and the other tissue with the same rsid for the same gene has -ve value then it should be yellow.

I used this code:

```
chr22_gene <- as.matrix(chr22_gene)
> heatmap(chr22_gene)
```

And generated this plot:
[image]
But I want it to look like this in form of a matrix:

```
       T1    T2       T3
Gene1  4      0        1
Gene2  2      1        2
```

so for gene1: we have 4rsid present in T1 only, for T2 no rsid and for T3 we see 1 rsid. Now let say if T1 all the four rsid are +ve and T3 rsid is -ve then have different opposite color for T1 and T3 in heatmap for the gene to show they have opposite signs.
Is there any way to do this in heatmap.
Thank you.